# constexpr function gets value at compile time even though my variable is not constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use https://github.com/gdelugre/literal_ipaddr which says it is a

> C++17 constexpr implementation of inet_addr / inet_aton / inet_pton

When I do:

```
auto ipSourceAddressTest = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>("127.0.0.1");
std::cout << "ipSourceAddressTest is " << ipSourceAddressTest.s_addr << std::endl;
```

This works fine. I get the IP address in decimal.

However:

```
std::string ipv4address;
//get ipv4address from world here
const unsigned int ipMaxSize = 200;
char ip[ipMaxSize];
std::copy(ipv4address.begin(), ipv4address.end(), ip);
auto ipSourceAddress = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip);
std::cout << "ipSourceAddress is " << ipSourceAddress.s_addr << std::endl;
```

Remember that `ipSourceAddress.s_addr` is `uint32_t`. The value I get printed is not the IP in decimal but in fact is `4294967295` which is `111...111` in binary. So I think it is getting its value at compile time rather than runtime.

If I do

```
constexpr auto in_addr1 = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip);
```

then it's understandable that its value will be deduces in compile time. But I didn't use `constexpr` in my variable declaration. Does `auto` implies `constexpr`?

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr,

> A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable
>   (since C++17) declaration implies inline

so why the function `inet_pton` is getting its value in compile time?

Comment: How do you know, that it is computed at compile time? Did you look at generated assembly? Note: Your `ip` array is uninitialized (because `ipv4address` is empty, and `std::copy` does nothing, due to that), hence using it, is undefined behavior.

Comment: A `constexpr` function can be called at runtime. It's only calculated at compile-time if possible.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ipv4address is not empty, in the comment I am getting it from the world.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I event `cout`ed `ipv4address` just to make sure and it is indeed not empty, and even `ip` is copied correctly.

Comment: How did you `get ipv4address from world`? This is important for locating your problem.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin it's a very complicated process (OpenVPN gives me this IP address after connection). But if I can print `ipv4address` and `ip` correctly before calling `auto ipSourceAddress = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip);` then it should work, rigth?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs "_ipv4address is not empty, in the comment I am getting it from the world._" Then, please provide [mre]. More on that: is `ip` being treated as null-terminated string (C-string) in `IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip);`? If so, it's undefined behavior, even if `ipv4address` is not empty, since `std::copy` wouldn't copy the null-terminator.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs [Algirdas Preidžius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440453/algirdas-preidžius) is correct on this. Try `IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ipv4address.c_str())`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I tried `strcpy(ip, ipv4address.c_str());`. It also didn't work. It should have copied the null terminator too, rigth? So I guess that's not the problem

Comment: @KaenbyouRin the signature is `template <int AddressF, size_t N>
static constexpr auto inet_pton(const char (&str)[N])` so I can't pass a c_str() because it has undefined size. I must pass a fixed size char*, that's why I created the `ip` variable

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Looking at the library, it seems to be meant primarily for compile-time use and accepts only `char` arrays, not pointers.

Comment: Is that possibly your netmask?

Comment: @Chipster no/ ....

Comment: The speculation in the question and title is very misleading.  Can you cheat from the answer and rewrite it to be about the actual, interesting, issue of array references versus decayed pointers?  (And use `std::strcpy`, since `std::copy` is wrong here anyway.  Maybe even try and fail to use `ipv4address.c_str()`, since that’s what ought to work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipSourceAddress` does not get its value at compile time (as-if rule nonwithstanding).

`ip`'s value is not usable in a constant expression since it is not declared `constexpr` and doesn't qualify for one of the other exceptions to the rule of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in a constant expression. Therefore `IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip)` is not a constant expression.

You can see this clearly by making `ipSourceAddress` `constexpr` (which `auto` does not imply).

`constexpr` on a variable requires initialization at compile-time and because the initializer is not a constant expression it will fail.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rUcCaS).

I don't know how you come to a different conclusion.

---

Note however that the library does seem to require that the `char` array passed to it is exactly as long as the string it contains (plus null-terminator). It fails if you hand it a longer array and outputs the value you are seeing.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Cn8qSM).

It seems the author intends the functions to only be called directly with string literals.

Comment: So if "constexpr on a variable requires initialization at compile-time" then it means that I can't use `IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip)` in any way except if for values known at compile time? Why would someone create such a limited library?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No, if you don't use `constexpr` it is going to be executed at runtime and there is no problem. You don't need the `constexpr`. That being said, having had a look at the library, the author seems to indeed have had *only* compile time in mind, since they did not provide an overload taking a `char*` for pure runtime use. Why exactly do you need this library anyway? why not use the POSIX functions directly?

Comment: But I didn't use `constexpr`. I simply did `auto ipSourceAddress = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>(ip);`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs yes, and there is nothing wrong with that. I don't understand what problem you are having with it.

Comment: the problem is that instead of getting the decimal version of my IP address (192.168.255.18) I get `4294967295` which is `111...111` in binary. I even added an std::cout before calling `inet_pton` and it indeed prints the IP address `ip` corretly. However if I do the same but instead with constexpr like this: `constexpr auto in_addr1 = IPAddr::inet_pton<AF_INET>("192.168.255.18");` I get a true decimal value.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I had a look at the library, see my edited answer. It does not seem to be intended for your use case. I suggest you simply use the POSIX `inet_pton` instead.

Comment: Any idea *why* it’s written to work only with character arrays (and without checking for NUL)?  You can read string literals and character arrays at constexpr time with ordinary `const char*` parameters…

Comment: @DavisHerring They templated all functions on the length of the `char` array, which as you say is not necessary and makes me think that the author either wasn't aware of it or never intended any other use except directly with string literals.

Comment: @DavisHerring The particular error mentioned in my answer is because loops are conditions on this templated size, not the null-terminator. The return statement in [this line](https://github.com/gdelugre/literal_ipaddr/blob/master/ipaddr.h#L125) is triggered, returning `-1`, presumably supposed to indicate an error condition, but the error is never reported. Instead the value is combined (for all four address components) into the output. Why all of this is written this way, I have no clue.